# Why Intelij inserts space after final parameter in annotations when using Reformat Code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

Why does Intelij randomly decided to insert space after final parameter in every annotation.

How it was until now:

```
@GetMapping("/something")
@Tag(name = "Something", description = "Something")
```

How it is now:

```
@GetMapping("/something" )
@Tag(name = "Something", description = "Something" )
```

I did not change anything in formatter settings, just noticed that after running "Reformat Code" on whole project I have changes in every annotation.

I checked Settings > Code Style > Java > Spaces > Annotation parentheses - is not checked

Comment: Okay, I found the solution. I don't know what happened, but restarts etc. did not help. What fixed the issue was invalidating cache.